# CursorLoader  из нескольких таблиц

Tags: android

Доброго  времени  суток.

Есть  фрагмент, в нем мне нужно через CursorLoader подгружать данные с разных табли БД. Как это реализовать?

Буду  рад  полезной  информации.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
getLoaderManager().initLoader(id1, null, loader);
getLoaderManager().initLoader(id2, null, loader);

LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> loader = new LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>() {
    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        switch(id){...}
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader loader, Cursor data) {
        switch(loader.getId()){...}
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader loader) {
        switch(loader.getId()){...}
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы какую подгрузку имеете в виду?
Связанный запрос что ли нужно организовать между разными таблицами или, по очереди сначала из одной показывать, потом из другой, или просто свалить в кучу записи из одной и из другой?
Последний вариант возможен по логике СУБД если только у двух таблиц либо все поля совершенно одинаковы, либо вы будете в селекте указывать поля которые хотя бы по типу данных совпадают.
Или я так чего-то не понимаю... Но в общем наверное уже не важно, т.к. ответ вроде бы принятый есть :)

Comment: Из одной  потом  из другой. Не  связанные. Но  по  разным  ListView.